# plotting a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a sample of size 180.And I would like to plot this using matlab.That is, X-axis with 1 to 180 and Y-axis these 180 independent values(180 sample values). Can someone help me with how to proceed.
What is the easiest way to do this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you probably can't imagine 180 dimensional space. So this is likely not worth doing.

Comment: If `y` is an array that contains your 180 data values, just type `plot(y)`.